# Navigation drawer is under other widgets

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add **fragment with Navigation drawer** to the main activity, where are two buttons. However, when Navigation drawer is opened, buttons are **above** it. Moreover, Navigation drawer is **not clickable**, but buttons are.

[Screenshot of opened Navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDUtm.png)

Here is my code.

**XML File implementing Navigation Drawer - MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainTestsButton"
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="334dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="167dp"
    android:onClick="goTest"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainLearningButton"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="175dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
    android:onClick="goLearn"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentList"
        android:name="com.chemistryApps.NavigationDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Navigation Drawer XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".NavigationDrawer">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_layout" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Navigation Drawer Fragment Java class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;


public class NavigationDrawer extends Fragment {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public NavigationDrawer() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static NavigationDrawer newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    NavigationDrawer fragment = new NavigationDrawer();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("buttonClicked", "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    mDrawerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {
            Log.i("buttonClicked", "onDrawerOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {
            Log.i("buttonClicked", "onDrawerOpened");
            navigationView.bringToFront();
            mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {
            Log.i("buttonClicked", "onDrawerOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {
            Log.i("buttonClicked", "onDrawerOpened");
        }
    });


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    Log.i("buttonClicked", "onNavigationItemSelected()" + menuItem.toString());
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.learning:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LearningActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.test:
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.settings:
                            return true;
                        case R.id.help:
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;

                    }


                }
            });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, 
false);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for an answer.

**EDIT:**
I am attaching the **main activity code**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationDrawer.OnFragmentInteractionListener {



public void goLearn (View view){
    Log.i("buttonClicked", "goLearn");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LearningActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goTest (View view){
    Log.i("buttonClicked", "goTest");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: attach your activity code as well.

Comment: where you are using layout with buttons?

Comment: Add **background color** to main view of your fragment (i.e. `DrawerLayout` here for your fragment). also, make your `NavigationView` **clickable**.

Comment: @NoumanCh I am using layout with buttons in MainActvity, which I attached now.

Comment: basically you need to add navigatin drawer inside activity xml instead of fragment xml.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I added background color to DrawerLayout and made NavigationView clickable, but the result is still the same .

Comment: @NoumanCh so it is not possible to use navigation drawer as a fragment?

Comment: Try `Framelayout` for `MainActivity` as root view once.

Comment: @JeelVankhede tried `Framelayout` and no change.